# R - Shiny App - Using plotly to visualize shinyMatrix input

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, reactive

)

I would like to visualize the input of a `shinyMatrix` using a `plotly`mesh3d-plot. I was using a `for-loop` to convert the matrix input into a data frame having 3 columns (x, y and z) - see below. This works when being run outside the shiny app. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with using this for-loop inside a `reactive()` environment to pass this into `plot_ly()`. It says "object of type closure is not subsettable". I read, that this error often comes if you don't treat your reactive object as a function (which I did).

I know that I'm a beginner and I don't have much clue about the syntax of a shiny app. Most likely I did a supid mistake :-) But I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- fluidPage(   titlePanel("shinyMatrix: Simple App"),   
                   sidebarPanel(width = 6,tags$h4("Data"),     
                                     matrixInput("mat", 
                                                 value = matrix(1:100, 10, 10), 
                                                 rows = list(names=T, extend = TRUE), 
                                                 cols = list(names = TRUE))),
                   mainPanel(width = 6,
                             plotlyOutput(
                                 "plotly",
                                 width = "100%",
                                 height = "400px",
                                 inline = FALSE,
                                reportTheme = TRUE
                             ))) 
   
 
server <- function(input, output, session) {  

df <- data.frame(x="", y="", z="")   

df <- reactive({    
    n=1
    for(i in 1:nrow(input$mat)){
        for(j in 1:ncol(input$mat)){
            df[n,1] <- j*laenge
            df[n,2] <- i*laenge
            df[n,3] <- input$mat[i,j]
            n=n+1
        }
    } 
    })

output$plotly <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(df(), x=~x, y=~y, z=~z, type="mesh3d")})   
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is that you used the same name `df` for both the reactive and the dataframe. Additionally your reactive has to return something to make your code work, i.e. return the dataframe after your for-loops.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dd <- data.frame(x = NA, y = NA, z = NA)

  df <- reactive({
    n <- 1
    for (i in 1:nrow(input$mat)) {
      for (j in 1:ncol(input$mat)) {
        dd[n, 1] <- j * laenge
        dd[n, 2] <- i * laenge
        dd[n, 3] <- input$mat[i, j]
        n <- n + 1
      }
    }
    dd
  })

  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(df(), x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "mesh3d")
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice weekend :-)